# Add space in the bottom of chrome dev console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Each Time I'm using this console I'm struggeling with my mouse to click on the editable line.

So two question :

- Is there a way of enlarging this line so it easier to click on it ?
- Is there a command to navigate to it ?

[image]

Comment: I've edited it so it is maybe a bit more clear

Comment: `Ctrl-~` focuses the input box. I agree it's too cramped visually but there's no way to customize it unless you're willing to patch the style in resources.pak on every update. Consider submitting a feature request on https://crbug.com

Answer (score 2):

The only way to enlarge it is to create a custom theme for DevTools, enable the experiment for using custom themes, and then installing your extension. That way you can get custom CSS into the top-level DevTools scope to modify things.

You may open a bug report on the [chromium issue tracker](https://crbug.com/new) against the DevTools so the team can assess the UX to see if there is anything they should modify internally.